# Ratchet transitions not working with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ratchet-bootstrap

I have built an mobile app using the ui compenent ratchet and angularjs. As far everythings works fine. I wanna use transitions when switching between pages, but this feature does not work. I'm using following transition definition:

```
<a href="#/test" data-transition="slide-in">
    <strong>Testing page</strong>
    <span class="chevron"></span>
</a>
```

In index.html i also try to catch the ratchet push event when clicking on the link above. No events occur.

```
// Catch push event fired by ratchet
window.addEventListener('push', function(){
console.log("push event occurred")
});
```

How can make push.js and angularjs play nicely together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `data-ignore="push"` to `<a>`, or don't include the push.js file. If you are using the unified ratchet.js, use better the separated js files.